WooCommerce breadcrumbs: Replacing "Home" with an icon from an icon library
I wanted to replace the home breadcrumb with a Material Symbol icon (The Google icon library). But it just displays 'home' instead of using the actual icon.

I found the following code in another thread:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'jk_change_breadcrumb_home' );
function jk_change_breadcrumb_home( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['before'] = '<span class="material-symbols-outlined">';
    $defaults['after'] = '</span>';
    $defaults['home'] = 'home';
    return $defaults;
}

But what it does is that it wraps the entirety of the breadcrumb with a 'before' and 'after', which leads the 'shop' mention to display the 'shop' icon of the material symbols library.

